# Redis disconnecting and reconnecting on Twisted periodically

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, twisted, disconnect

I have Twisted server with constant connection to Redis.
I'm using library https://github.com/fiorix/txredisapi.

Problem is that from time to time Twisted lose connection to Redis and reconnects shortly after. I have no idea why. 
Same thing is happening both on my local machine and on my online VPS.

Log:

```
2013-04-12 11:25:34+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0xf6c45d4c> will retry in 10 seconds
2013-04-12 11:25:34+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] Stopping factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:25:45+0200 [-] Starting factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:30:47+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0xf6c45d4c> will retry in 10 seconds
2013-04-12 11:30:47+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] Stopping factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:30:58+0200 [-] Starting factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:35:59+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0xf6c45d4c> will retry in 10 seconds
2013-04-12 11:35:59+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] Stopping factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:36:10+0200 [-] Starting factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:41:12+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0xf6c45d4c> will retry in 8 seconds
2013-04-12 11:41:12+0200 [RedisProtocol,client] Stopping factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 11:41:21+0200 [-] Starting factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
```

It happens all day and all night, my logs are getting big quickly.

Log when someone connects while redis is disconnected:

```
2013-04-12 12:29:58+0200 [HTTPPageGetter,client] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-04-12 12:29:58+0200 [HTTPPageGetter,client] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.ConnectionError: Not connected
2013-04-12 12:30:03+0200 [-] Starting factory <lib.txredisapi.txredisapi.RedisFactory instance at 0xf6c45ccc>
2013-04-12 12:30:22+0200 [Protocol,20,89.73.182.51] Connection from 89.73.182.51:38635 closed. Code: 1006, Reason: connection was closed uncleanly (peer dropped the TCP connection without previous WebSocket closing handshake)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I got answer from creator of txredisapi. In config there is timeout setting which by default is set to 300 seconds. So simple.

Comment: Can you please share more details?

Comment: Author of txredisapi here. The change is actually in redis.conf, where you should set the timeout to zero.

Comment: @fiorix hi, first thanks for great library. I am getting same issue even after setting timeout 0 in my redis.conf.  using latest redis 3.2.8 and txredisapi v1.4.4